# Binding in windows/wpf and asp.net model

Tags: asp.net, wpf, winforms, data-binding

Binding data to DataBound controls in winforms and wpf vs Asp.Net has a slight difference

WPF/Winforms

```
dataBoundControl.DataSource = someDataSource;
```

Asp.Net

```
dataBoundControl.DataSource = someDataSource;
dataBoundControl.DataBind();  //<----- the difference
```

Question: what is the difference between these two models that makes one require the use `.DataBind()` and the other does not? Why doesn't the winforms/wpf require `.DataBind()` and why does Asp.Net requires it?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think that is requires it - you call it if you like to update the content if (and after) you change the Data on DataSource. If you not call it, is call it the first time the page runs.

Comment: @Aristos I don't think so too. I have experienced that several times and many users have asked such questions on stackOverflow - "why the Grid is not showing data/empty" and most response would be - "hey, you need to call `.DataBind()`"

Comment: I can not argue because my experience is only on asp.net controls and not on both (asp.net and windows/wpf). Ah, now from what you say.... yes you need to call the `.DataBind()` if you change the data.